# Combine multiple ngrx subscribe into one

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I currently subscribe on a `selector` to `dispatch` an action and I subscribe on that as well but I was wondering how I can combine them so I don't need to use a `subscribe` in a `subscribe`

```js
this.store$
  .pipe(
    select(getStateParams),
    isNotNullOrUndefined(),
    map(({ id }) => ({
      id,
    })),
    isNotNullOrUndefinedObjectProperties(),
    stringObjectPropertiesToNumbers(),
    take(1),
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$)
)
.subscribe(({ id }) => {
  this.store$.dispatch(
    updateContent({
      id
    })
  ).subscribe(() => { //...do something)}
});
```

I have been playing around with `switchMap` and `mergeMap` but can't seem to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwitchMap should work just fine... what have you tried?

For example:

```ts
this.store$.pipe(
  
  select(getStateParams),
  isNotNullOrUndefined(),
  map(({ id }) => ({ // <- This map is a null operation
    id,              // Why is it here? What are you 
  })),               // Hoping that this does?
  isNotNullOrUndefinedObjectProperties(),
  stringObjectPropertiesToNumbers(),
  switchMap(idOby => this.store$.dispatch(
    updateContent(idOby)
  )),
  take(1),
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$)

).subscribe(() => { 
  //...do something
});
```